# How to do custom formatting of build stats with webpack-dev-middleware?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-middleware

I am currently using the [basic Webpack API](https://webpack.github.io/docs/node.js-api.html) with a custom printer for the build results, i.e.:

```
import webpack from 'webpack'

webpack({ /* webpack config */ }, printStats)

function printStats(err, stats) {
  // my custom printing of build results
}
```

Now I want to switch to using [`webpack-dev-middleware`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-middleware.html), but retain my stat printer. I would expect maybe this to work:

```
import webpackDev from 'webpack-dev-middleware'

app.use(webpackDev(webpack({ /* webpack config */ }, printStats), {
    quiet: true // disable default printing so I can use my own
    // ... more webpack-dev-middelware configuration
}))
```

but it only prints the first compilation and ignores subsequent ones even though they do take place. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by listening directly to the Webpack compiler object via the `plugin` method:

```
const compiler = webpack({ /* webpack config */ })

compiler.plugin('done', stats => {
  // my custom printing of build results
})

app.use(webpackDev(compiler, {
  quiet: true // disable default printing so I can use my own
  // ... more webpack-dev-middelware configuration
}))
```

The `done` event occurs every time compilation finishes, successfully or otherwise. Other events you can listen to via the `plugin` method:

- `'run'`: Indicates that a one-off compilation is taking place. Aynchronous; listener takes the compiler object and callback function which must be invoked to indicate the listener is done handling the event.
- `'watch-run'`: Indicates that the source is being compiled or recompiled in watch mode. Aynchronous; listener takes the compiler object and callback function which must be invoked to indicate the listener is done handling the event.
- `'invalid'`: Indicates that a change was detected to the source in the course of watching it (will be followed shortly by a `watch-run` event. Synchronous; listener takes no arguments.